# Inconsistent use of punctuation in error messages

Tags: bug, error-message

Inconsistent use of punctuation in error messages: `seconds` vs `seconds.`

Example with "**seconds.**":

[image: seconds. (has period) picture]

Example with "**seconds**":

[image: seconds (no period) picture]

Comment: Is there a "correct" use? Or is that an opinion based black hole?

Comment: @rene Unsure about correctness, but better be consistent.

Comment: @rene either one is probably fine, but they should be consistent. Kind of like the Oxford comma.

Comment: @TheWanderer [Beware of that comma](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47135/3023) ;)

Comment: These are complete sentences, so use of a comma is correct. I also agree with Franck that consistency is even more important when it comes to UI.